# which type of data structure is best?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

In my application, we already have

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

Now we got another use-case where need to find a key which is mapped to a particular string inside the list.

I am thinking of writing following:

```
string getKey(Map<String, List<String>> m, String str) {
  for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry :m.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue().contains(str)) {
      retrun entry.getKey();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

`Map` can have at max 2000 entries. and each `List` can have at max 500 `String`s.

Any suggestions that might be a better fit? I can change the initial data structure (`Map`) also if there is a better way to do it..

Comment: You can use `Set<String>` instead of `List<String>` as `contains()` method is much faster on `Set`. If you `Map` is large then you can think of adding another Map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you add another map that gives the reverse mapping - from a string to list of keys. This will require a bit more of work to keep in sync with the first map but will give the best performance for your task.

Still if you think the frequency of such queries will be relatively low, maybe your solution could be better(although slower, the time you save for keeping both maps in sync will make up for that).

Comment: number of such type of queries can be around 3000. If I have another map I will end up having 1 million entries out of which I query only 3000 times.

Comment: @vikas368 yes but with the map each of the 3000 queries could be linear with respect to the size of the answer, while without this map each query will be linear with respect to **all** entries. Take this into account and think if its worth the optimization. I am guessing for 3000 it is probably better to use the solution I propose.

Comment: finally I am going with having another map

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with Guava API? If you have the liberty to add/change dependencies, it's definitely worth checking out, particularly implementations of the [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface. It's exactly built for those cases where the same key can be mapped to multiple values.

In case I misunderstood the question and the same key will not be mapped to multiple values then you might need to reformulate/rethink your question as your current idea `Map<String, List<String>>` is essentially just that.

Comment: I need the current mapping string -> list. In addition to that, we have now above mentioned use-case.

Comment: I am allowed to add dependencies but I never used Guava API. Can you point me to some examples of MultiMap?

Comment: take a look at the example in the doc pages in the link I gave above. `Multimap` implementations are nice in the sense that you don't have to bother with managing the `List`s.

Comment: I went through MultiMap, it is interesting. But I could not find any method which gives key for a particular value. am I missing something here?

Comment: hmm... how about a `BiMap` then? :) It's a bi-directional `Map` http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Comment: BitMap is also good, but I need both BitMap as well as MultiMap Properties ;) any more suggestions?